# Recommendations for cron-like scheduling in Grails: run method once every hour

Tags: grails

Suppose I want to run the following method `foo()` once every hour in Grails:

```
class FooController {
  public static void foo() {
    // stuff that needs to be done once every hour (at *:00)
  }
}
```

What is the easiest/recommended way to set up such cron-like scheduling in Grails?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Quartz plugin: http://grails.org/plugin/quartz

> Adds Quartz job scheduling features...
>
> Starting from 1.0-RC3, this plugin uses Quartz 2.1.x, and no longer uses Quartz 1.8.x. If you want to use Terracotta 3.6+, this is the plugin to use. This is because the other 'quartz2' plugin doesn't use JobDetailsImpl class, which Terracotta 3.6 requires. See https://jira.terracotta.org/jira/browse/QTZ-310 for more info...
>
> Full documentation can be found [here](http://grails-plugins.github.com/grails-quartz/)

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to add another plugin dependency, an alternative is to use the JDK Timer class. Simply add the following to `Bootstrap.groovy`

```
def init = { servletContext ->
    // The code for the task should go inside this closure
    def task = { println "executing task"} as TimerTask

    // Figure out when task should execute first
    def firstExecution = Calendar.instance

    def hour = firstExecution.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)
    firstExecution.clearTime()
    firstExecution.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour + 1)

    // Calculate interval between executions
    def oneHourInMs = 1000 * 60 * 60

    // Schedule the task
    new Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(task, firstExecution.time, oneHourInMs) 
}
```